# 10.12 Sierra Mail not rendering some emails correctly

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

I have Apple Mail and Airmail 3 running side by side. Emails from lists which used to be perfectly rendered are now rendered by Apple Mail as text, while still being correctly rendered by Airmail 3. What's up?

Example, rendered by Apple Mail:

[image]

And here's the same message rendered by Airmail 3:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to an image rendering bug in the new version of Apple Mail (Sierra).

When an <img> element in an HTML mail doesn't have both a "width" and a "height" attribute, the image is not displayed the first time the email is opened. If both attributes are defined, the image is properly displayed. If either one or both are missing, the image is not displayed.

The same <img> element is properly rendered in previous versions of Apple Mail.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me, was surprisingly simple.

1. Select the relevant mail box.
2. From the menubar, select "Mailbox" then choose "Rebuild".

I have tried this menu item several times over the years when trying to address various issues with mail, always without success. On this occasion, with exactly the same symptoms you describe this fixed the issue.

Note: it may take several minutes to complete the Rebuild… do not close Mail as this will interrupt the process.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I receive emails, some with place cards and a ? inside and others which show the image. Both are links to a website and if clicked on the shown image takes you to that website page, the unshown image i.e. the place card with a ? inside, when clicked on takes you to the web page but still no images shown. I believe this is due to the image being an.aspx format that my mac mail cannot decipher. If you drag the place card image into a browsers' url then it does open the page with images shown.
[image]
This is a screenshot of the raw data from an email that will not load images all said images end with format .aspx there does not appear to be a solution apart from opening using a windows based email client instead of a mac email client, my macbook mail client is version 7.3 (1878.6)

Comment: `.aspx` is not an image format.  It's the extension for *Active Server Page*; a web page built on Microsoft IIS Server.  It's similar to `.html`.  You;re not linking images, you're linking pages.